# Is there any truncation?

Tags: c++, truncation

I am trying to calculate the radius of a ball that can be made if I have leather with 4195065486 mm2 area and 1 mm thickness, starting from a small ball with radius = 1 mm the maker can wrap up the leather as multilayer around the ball. I wrote this code to get the radius of the ball which can be made and the area which will remain from the leather. (assuming that pi=3.14159).

```
double A, r;
const double pi=3.14159;
double AreaCalc(double r);
int main(){

    A=4195065486.0;
    r=1.0;
    double final_r = AreaCalc(r); 
    cout<<final_r<<"  "<<A<<"  "<<endl;
    return 0;
}

double AreaCalc(double r){
    double ca;

    ca=4*pi*r*r;
    if (A-ca>=0.0){

        A=A-ca;
        AreaCalc(r+1);
    }
    else return r;
}
```

Is there any truncation or influence which may cause an inaccurate result of `A`?
By debugging i can get A=12559904.940002432.

Comment: What is your output and what do you expect?

Comment: If you're going to use double precision then you should at least use a suitably accurate value of π - preferably use `M_PI` from `<cmath>`.

Comment: @PaulR: The question assumes that pi = 3.14159 not less or more.

Comment: @PaulR (Or `4 * atan(1)` if `M_PI` is not available.)

Comment: You have a *very* strange mixture of globals, locals, parameters, and return values. Globals have a tendency to make recursion very tricky to follow and induce bugs.

Comment: Much easier: from the area and thickness of the leather calculate its volume. Now calculate the radius of a ball with this volume.

Comment: @Henrik: I don't think this is possible, because the idea is to wrap up the leather with already-existing ball, and if I use your method there will be on chance for any remaining leather.

Comment: @Aan just take `floor(radius in mm)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `return` in the `if`-branch, causing undefined behaviour.
Add it:

```
return AreaCalc(r+1);
```

You should have got a compiler warning for that.
If you didn't, increase your warning level.
If you did, start paying attention to warnings. Your compiler's "Treat warnings as errors" option is a very healthy choice.

(But, like @Henrik suggests in the comments, maths is the best solution.)

Comment: Mysterious echo far from the background: "And compile with warnings enabled...! warnings enabled...! enabled...! led...!"